# Spring Login user information retreival

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am creating a Basic Spring Web application that involves a User logging in and entering their personal dashboard. I have utilised the Default Spring Security Login form when the "login" url is instantiated through the controller. What I would like the know is, how do I retrieve the users personal account information which just logged in from the database?
This is what I had in the controller class when the login url had been instantiated

```
@RequestMapping("dashboard")
public String goDashboard(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("user", new User());
    return "dashboard"; // this is just returning the viewResolver JSP page
}
```

I am assuming the above is incorrect, as I personally think that making a new Object is wrong and will give me null values. When I login and try to display using:`<c:out value="${user.username}" />` Nothing gets displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can get it in your controller:

```
@RequestMapping("dashboard")
public String goDashboard(Model model, Principal principal){
    model.addAttribute("username", principal.getName());
    return "dashboard"; 
}
```

Such approach will help you keep business logic in controller (separation of concerns).

**EDIT.** Pass user details object:

```
@RequestMapping("dashboard")
public String goDashboard(Model model, Principal principal){
    UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails)((Authentication)principal).getPrincipal()
    model.addAttribute("userDetails", userDetails);
    return "dashboard"; 
}
```

Comment: Great thankyou! Alhtough am I limited to only displaying the username in this case? Or can I access all the database fields this way? For example: password, email, biogrpahy, etc..

Comment: Of course you can pass complete user datails object into your view. My answer is updated.

Comment: I still cannot get my other values to show from the database. After implementing the code above, I can dsiplay only my 'username' like this: <c:out value="userDetails.username"/> but if I try that same coed with 'userDetails.email' it does not work and I get JasperException error 500 code

Comment: Do you use a custom UserDetails object? Is it has an additional **email** field? This field is populated during autentication?

Comment: I just implemented what you had wrote above in your edited code snippet, and just casted (UserDetails) before the (Authentication)principal.getPrincipal();

Comment: By default UserDetails object is populated by spring security only with fields [listed here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#d4e3668). If you want some additional fields then you need to: 1) Add your custom bean that implements UserDetailsService 2) Add your CustomuserDetails object that extends UserDetails 3) fill and return this object from `UserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(...)` method

Comment: 4) configure Spring Security to use your custom UserDetailsService instead of default one as in first example [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#ns-auth-providers).

Comment: If you want to ad some fields that may be changed during some user session then it may be better to load your User object from DB by name in the controller and pass it to the view. Remember that changes on User in DB are not reflected to in-memory UserDetails object.

Answer (score 0):

if you create new `User` object, the username will be null definitely (if you have empty default constructor only).
You can get username in jsp like this:

```
<sec:authentication property="principal.username" />
```

and don't forget to add declaration on top:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>
```

Read more about it [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/taglibs.html)

Comment: Excellent! It worked, thank you. Is this the correct way of implementing it? Or Is it better to make a principal Object in the Controller or something?

Comment: @user2660806 it's correct. If you need to get principal in the controller, just add parameter `Principal principal`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it in various ways.

1) Using [SecurityContextHolder](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/context/SecurityContextHolder.html):

```
Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
```

and then put it into the model as you do now.

2) Using [Spring Security Taglibs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/taglibs.html):

```
<sec:authentication property="principal.username" /> // will render name
```

In this case you do not need to add any code to the controller.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like there are several options I can use. My only question is what is the most correct way of doing it?(Keeping it MVC) and by using the <sec:authentication property="principal.username" /> I am only limited to getting 2 database fields from the Database is this correct?

Comment: If you are 100% sure you'll need only 2 fields - you can use taglibs and do not worry.

Comment: What if I need more then 2 Feilds? I tried loading all my database fields with: <sec:authentication property="principal.username" /> but changing 'username' to corresponding fields and it just returned null. It didnt work

Comment: You'd better read the docs and try to find out what real class you get. There are different objects - `Principal`, `Authentication`, and I do not remember what exact the difference between them is. Also, it is a good exercise for you.

Comment: If you need more than two fields, or you need complex logic with Principal - you should use it in Controller. IMHO, `sec:authentication` is not an MVC-way, because you got logic on your JSPs, not using model. But for simple cases it is good enough. So the final answer what to use is - "it depends..."

Comment: Yeah great! Thanks for the help, I am trying to implement it into the controller now, although I cant seem to get it.